# 3D surface 'surf' not giving any result

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I have values of the parameters `a`, `b` and `P`. The shape or surface `S` is related to them in the following manner.

`S = P (1- x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2)^0.5`

I would also want to give the minimum value of scale as `-a`, `-b` and maximum values as `a`, `b` during the figure generation.

Here is an MWE of the problem with given values of `a=1.777`, `b=0.228` and `P=1.642`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.3,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={a},
    ylabel={b}, 
    colormap/jet
    ]
    \addplot3[surf]
    {1.642 * (1 - x^2/1.777^2 -y^2/0.228^2)^0.5};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It should produce an image like the one given below (generated from matlab). 
[image: Desired image]

However, all it is giving is a blank figure with axis like this. What can be done to fix it?

[image: Resulting image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pgfplots` cannot deal with complex numbers.  You could declare a new function `realsqrt` which only takes the real part of the square root and returns 0 for complex arguments.

To get rid of the blue base at `z=0` one could use

```
\addplot3[point meta={z<=0 ? nan : z},...]
```

but then one has to crank up the sampling beyond good and evil to get rid of the jagged border.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={realsqrt(\x) = ifthenelse(\x<0,0,sqrt(\x));}
  ]
    \begin{axis}[
      domain=-2:2,
      y domain=-.3:.3,
      xlabel={a},
      ylabel={b}, 
      colormap/jet,
      samples=41,
      ]
      \addplot3[surf,shader=interp]
      {1.642 * realsqrt(1 - x^2/1.777^2 - y^2/0.228^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified the following code to get rid of the blue base without any additional computational cost by replacing your lines with these: `[
 declare function={realsqrt(\x) = ifthenelse(\x<0,-1,sqrt(\x));}
 ]
 \begin{axis}[zmin=0, zmax=2,`. However, now I only want to be able to reset values of colorbar according to current figure being shown. Is it possible? Please let me know, if my question isn't clear. I will try to post it separately.

Comment: Okay, I got even more acceptable results by replacing `-1` in above comment with `-0.4`. Seems to suffice for now with slight problem in orientation. Any comments to improve it?